# Formationing Algorithm for Multiple Robots

Tags: mobile-robot, multi-agent, swarm

I'm looking for an algorithm for formationing multiple robots in 2D simulation. Can you suggest resources about this topic. Also I need suggestions and comments about these topics:

- Can I recruit algorithm from optimization algorithms like particle or ant?
- Is there any way except "go to goal" for each robot
- Is patter formationing algorithms feasible?
- Suggestions about a fast way of formationing/ aligning

Notes:

- Im not using a robotics simulator or physics engine for this.
- Robots are represented as dots.
- multi robot system is homogeneous
- every robot can sense obstacles and other robots in a sense range circle around the robot.
- number of obstacles and robots can vary from 2 to 100
- multi robot system is not a central

Comment: Which kind of sensors do your robots have? Do they know where they are? In which direction they are looking? Or can you only sense your neighbours? How many robots do you have? Can you rely on a central master or do the robots have to negotiate?

Comment: @FooBar question edited.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs more on Stack Overflow as it has no relation to robotics except in name, it more accurately an algorithm question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the papers of the [kilobot project](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/ssr/projects/progSA/kilobot.html%20Kilobot). They have your capabilities so it would be a good starting point.